# How to turn the car when pressing left or right key

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to canvas and developing a game where a car moves straight and now I want to turn the car to anti clockwise when the left key is pressed and clockwise when right key is pressed.

Currently I am trying with

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/car.png";
  if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
  drawSprite(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y, scale = 1,angle = 90);    
}
```

But this does not work at all.I only want the car to be turned and not the screen.Any help is appreciated.
My source code: [working pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to the answer on this one: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67274/is-it-possible-to-rotate-an-image-on-an-html5-canvas-without-rotating-the-whole.

Basically:

1. Save the canvas coordinate system first (ctx.save()).
2. Rotate the canvas.
3. Draw your image in the rotated canvas.
4. Then restore the canvas coordinate (ctx.restore()).